# Gnome sort is faster than quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I decided to delve into sorting algorithms and implemented a few such as bubble, selection, gnome, insertion, merge and quick sort in python.  However when i ran them and compared the times, gnome sort which is O(n^2) was faster than quicksort which has a O(nlogn) i believe.  **Question: Can someone please explain to me why my gnome sort algorithm is faster than my quick and merge sort algorithms and ways to optimize my them so that they sort faster than the less efficient algorithms.**  Thank you.  (P.S. if you've never heard of gnome sort here's a link that will help [Wikipedia Gnome Sort Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort))

```
# Sorting lib
# author: Aniekan Umoren
# course: LEAP EngTech
# date started: 2016-08-09
# last modified: 2016-08-16

import time
from random import randrange

def bubble_sort(arr):
    k = 0
    n = len(arr)
    for numSweeps in range(n-1):
        for i in range(n-k-1):
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                temp = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[i+1]
                arr[i+1] = temp
        k += 1
    return arr

def selection_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    k = 0
    for numSweeps in range(n-1):
        minimum = arr[k]
        for i in range(k,n):
            if arr[i] < minimum:
                temp = arr[k]
                arr[k] = arr[i]
                arr[i] = temp
                minimum = arr[k]
        k += 1
    return arr

def gnome_sort(arr):
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(arr):
        if pos == 0 or arr[pos] >= arr[pos-1]:
            pos += 1
        else:
            temp = arr[pos]
            arr[pos] = arr[pos-1]
            arr[pos-1] = temp
            pos -= 1
    return arr

def insertion_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        x = arr[i]
        j = i -1
        while j >= 0 and arr[j] > x:
            arr[j+1] = arr[j]
            j -= 1
        arr[j+1] = x
    return arr

def merge(arr1,arr2):
    arr3 = []
    size1 = len(arr1); size2 = len(arr2)
    i1 = 0; i2 = 0
    while i1 < size1 or i2 < size2: #both list aren't empty
        if i1 == size1:
            arr3.append(arr2[i2])
            i2 += 1
        elif i2 == size2:
            arr3.append(arr1[i1])
            i1 += 1
        elif arr1[i1] <= arr2[i2]:
            arr3.append(arr1[i1])
            i1 += 1
        elif arr2[i2] < arr1[i1]:
            arr3.append(arr2[i2])
            i2 += 1
    return arr3

def merge_sort(Arr, start, end):
    if start < end:
        # size = (start + end + 1)
        mid = (start+end)//2
        arr1 = merge_sort(Arr,start, mid)
        arr2 = merge_sort(Arr, mid+1, end)
        Arr[start:end+1] = merge(arr1, arr2)
    return Arr[start:end+1]

def partition(Arr, start, end):
    rand = start + randrange(end-start)
    temp = Arr[start]
    Arr[start] = Arr[rand]
    Arr[rand] = temp
    i = start + 1
    for j in range(start+1, end+1):
        if Arr[j] < Arr[start]:
            temp = Arr[i]
            Arr[i] = Arr[j]
            Arr[j] = temp
            i += 1
    temp = Arr[start]
    Arr[start] = Arr[i-1]
    Arr[i-1] = temp
    return (Arr,i-1)

def quick_sort(Arr, start, end):
    if start < end:
        part_result = partition(Arr, start, end)
        Arr = part_result[0]
        piv_pos = part_result[1]
        quick_sort(Arr, start, piv_pos-1)
        quick_sort(Arr, piv_pos+1, end)
    if end == len(Arr)-1:
        return Arr


def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    li1 = [3, 1234, 123, 214, 21, 124, 125, 213,
           34, 354, 2345,62, 34, 623, 34, 34, 53465,
           346, 346434, 537373, 5347,73, 234, 62, 36,
           27, 247, 4742, 47472, 24, 742, 57, 24, 7245, 24]
    li2 = [3, 21, 24, 24, 27, 34, 34, 34, 34, 36,
           57, 62, 62, 73, 123, 124, 125, 213, 214,
           234, 247, 346, 354, 623, 724, 742, 1234,
           2345, 4742, 5347, 7245, 47472, 53465, 346434, 537373]
    li3 = sorted(li2, reverse = True)
    li4 = [3,5,26,42,2,6]

    for i in range(10000):
        result = bubble_sort(li1)
    print("BUBBLE SORT: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        result = gnome_sort(li1)
    print("GNOME SORT: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time)) # why is gnome sort sooo fast if it has a O(n**2)

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        result = selection_sort(li1)
    print("SELECTION SORT: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        result = insertion_sort(li1)
    print("INSERTION SORT: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

    size = len(li1)
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        result = merge_sort(li1, 0, size-1)
    print("MERGE SORT: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

    size = len(li1)
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        result = quick_sort(li1, 0, size-1)
    print("QUICK SORT: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        result = sorted(li1)
    print("TIM SORT: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

main()
```

Comment: awww why did I get a -1 vote?  I made my question as specific as possible and did research before asking.  What else do you guys want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sorts all mutate the input instead of returning a new list, so after the first sort, the input is sorted and stays sorted. Gnome sort is O(n) on already-sorted input.

Comment: Good spot. He'll need to copy the unsorted array and then sort the copy.

Comment: oh thankyou but why is it getting changed, its not as if i passed it by reference or something...

Comment: @AniekanUmoren: Python variables don't work the way you think they do. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: do any of you know why I got down voted?  So that i can avoid it in the future?